# How to fix VB.NET error 'Parameter not valid'?

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

I have created an application in VB.NET but when this code runs:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub gen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gen.Click
        Dim b As IronBarCode.GeneratedBarcode = IronBarCode.BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode(url.Text, IronBarCode.BarcodeWriterEncoding.QRCode)
        Dim bimg As Image = b.Image
        code.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom
        code.BackgroundImage = bimg
        transition.Hide(login)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get the error 'Parameter not valid' and the application enters break mode. I have tried inserting breakpoints in my code but I have not found where the error came from. How can I fix this?

Comment: If it isn't already, turn `Option Strict On` and see if the compiler flags anything. Otherwise, look at the stack trace of the exception to see where it happened and how execution got there.

Comment: What is _code_?

Comment: Clone the image. `Dim bimg As Image = Ctype(b.Image.Clone(), Image)`, and dispose of the current if any: `code.BackgroundImage?,Dispose()`, and set the new one: `code.BackgroundImage = bimg`. When `b` goes, `b.Image` goes. So you need to get a copy/clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

```
transition.Hide(login)
```

It is a component from an external library. The error was generated there.